# Update query is not working in codiegniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to update the records of stud table using codeigniter, but it did not updating the record, please see the following code of **Stud_edit.php** file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang = "en">
<head> 
  <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  <title>Students Example</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form method = "" action = "">
 <?php 
        echo form_open('Stud_controller/update_student'); 
        echo form_hidden('old_roll_no',$old_roll_no); 
        echo form_label('Roll No.'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no',
           'name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]->roll_no)); 
        echo "
        "; 

        echo form_label('Name'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name',
           'value'=>$records[0]->name)); 
        echo "
        "; 

        echo form_submit(array('id'=>'sub mit','value'=>'Edit')); 
        echo form_close();
     ?> 

  </form>
```

Following is code of controller :

```
public function update_student(){ 
     $this->load->model('Stud_Model');

     $data = array( 
        'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'), 
        'name' => $this->input->post('name') 
     ); 

     $old_roll_no = $this->input->post('old_roll_no'); 
     $this->Stud_Model->update($data,$old_roll_no); 

     $query = $this->db->get("stud"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Stud_view',$data); 
  }
```

And following is code of model  :

```
public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
     $this->db->set($data); 
     $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
     $this->db->update("stud", $data); 
  }
```

Comment: remove $this->db->set() line

Comment: change '$this->db->update("stud", $data);' to '$this->db->update("stud");'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using 2 `<form>` tags. Try to use one and use `method` attribute as well

```
<form method = "" action = "">
echo form_open('Stud_controller/update_student')
```

If you are using `set()` method to update query then don't use `$data` in the `update()` function

**Method 1**

without `set()` method

```
public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
 $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
 $this->db->update("stud", $data); 
}
```

**Method 2**

with `set()` method

```
public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
 $this->db->set($data);
 $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
 $this->db->update("stud"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Model :**

```
public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
     $this->db->where("roll_no", $old_roll_no); 
     $this->db->update("stud", $data); 
  }
```